# Invalid Syntax in Python 3.5.2 using Codeacademy functions

Tags: python-3.x, syntax

I'm trying to code in Python 3. So far I've used codeacademy to copy and paste the functions I've wanted. Unless what codeacademy uses is python 2 (which it's not, I've checked). So I'm curious why it highlights len and says invalid syntax.

```
print ('Have you thought today?') 

original = raw_input('Yes or No:')

If len(original) > 2:
    print ('When?')
```

Answer (score 2):

You put `If` capitalized. Python is case sensitive so you must use the correct keyword which is lowercase `if`.

Also `raw_input()` was renamed to `input()` in Python 3.

Comment: Is there a list of things that tell you everything that's been changed between py 2 and 3?

Comment: Here something: http://python3porting.com/differences.html But any list would be hard to read through it all if you don't really know what you are looking for, since there are so many changes.

Answer (score 0):

python3 doesn't have `raw_input()`.

Change

```
original = raw_input('Yes or No:')
```

to:

```
original = input('Yes or No:')
```

And, also use `if` in place of `If`.

Comment: `If` to `if` as well.

Comment: Oh, yes. I overlooked :(